# Too many icons, cannot see the clock

Tags: 20.04, top-bar

I've got too many icons in the top bar so the clock, which is located in the middle of the bar, is slowly starting to get obstructed. Is there a work-around for this situation?

my top bar:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are specific icons that you do not want to see, you can use a Gnome Extension called [Icon Hider](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/351/icon-hider/) to remove them from the status bar. This should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are using `gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor` for those graphs in there.

In the plugin's preferences, it allows you to assign a custom width to each of those graphs.

Can be configured either via right-click on the graphs > Preferences, or via Gnome-Tweaks window > Extensions > System-monitor > cogwheel button.

The default value is 100 (in pixels), what you also seem to have there; I for one have found that they are still pretty helpful at only 50 width.